# DNS not pointing to my website

Tags: dns, ip, hosting, propagation

I am very new to hosting. I have just got VPS with no prior experience (just a little bit working with in a shared hosting with Cpanel)

The VPS came with CentOS and Cpanel installed. So, I just needed to go through initial setup of WHM. I did not change any thing. Apparently, there name severs and an IP were already allocated to my host. I did not change them.

Right after Creating Cpanel for a website I already had somewhere else (and It was working), I went and changed the name servers of domain to names servers of my new host.

I know it can take up to 48 hrs for name servers to propagate through internet but it is close to 48hrs and I still have below situation

```
https://IP of my host -> new website shows up
http:// IP of my host -> websites doesn't show up(the gray sorry! page ....)
www.mywebsite.com -> websites doesn't show up (nothing at all)
```

I have already flushed my dns so it has nothing to do with cash

Observations:
I have checked with DNS checker websites. My dns name servers ARE propagated.
IP of name servers and my host IP is also returns positive.
just www.mydomain.com does not return result.

Should I wait more or there is something wrong with server configuration or do I need to reset something on server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying if you ping both your IP address and the domain name it returns connection values? But if you put into a browser it returns no pages? One suggestion is the web server is only connecting to https by port 443 and not port 80.

Comment: No. pinging the host IP returns value. Pinging name servers returns value. BUT pinging www.mydomain.com returns nothing

Comment: Again, on the web server that hosts the site does it have a connection for *.my website.com for port 80? As it must for port 443, as you claim you can pull that page up.

Comment: port 80 is open

Comment: Not really what I meant, a machine can have the port listening, the router can have access controls for that internal machine with that port; but no like IIS on a Microsoft machine can have multiple sites hosted but even with that ports for each site can be controlled within IIS. Just like different subdomains www or ftp can be directed to different machines or folders, so to can different ports be directed and controlled.

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea about what you said. my website address is www.tehran-rental.com    of course it is now just a page published by Cpanel site publisher till I set up actual site

Comment: If your paying a service to have someone host your website, maybe you should get with their IT staff. Because it would seem like you cannot access their router to see what ports are forwarding. In the same regard, how do you control the site names, connection strings, within their server without some kind of access to a Internet Management program which can also limit the ports that are accepted per site name?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a valid CNAME record set for www.yourdomain.com . If your non-www domain name works fine and the www doesn't , you should set a CNAME record for www.yourdomain.com to resolve to yourdomain.com .

Comment: No domain name works. only and only access to website index page is possible by directly typing IP address of host with https protocol in browser